# How to store tags in the url without a "?"

Tags: php

I'm wondering how I can store tags in a url without the ? and without keys.

eg. Google Product forums does this: http://productforums.google.com/forum/**#!topic/analytics/8qtK861a0iU**
Each topic wouldn't have it's own directory and so a server side script determines which topic to show visitors.

Does anybody know how it is possible to do this with PHP?

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for clean URL's?  Search for mod_rewrite and or PHP front controller as this question has been asked here 1000's of times.

Comment: Actually in your example, a server side script _doesn't_ determine which page to show. Hashes don't get sent to the server. The server loads the same page, javascript gets the hash, and makes a request to the server for the correct page, and loads the content. What you're looking at is called a hashbang, and what you want to do is called Pretty URLs (forget the hashbang, use HTML5 history API instead). [Search it up](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+make+pretty+urls&oq=how+to+make+pretty+urls).

Answer (score 0):

Google use a range of software to do this. one of which, can be done using .htaccess used on Apache servers (not IIS)

This is called modrewrite. A URL below can show an example of such tasks:

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Do start learning this, upload a file called `.htaccess` to your Apache driven webserver.